# Sending image as base64_encoded in json_payload on lumen API

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5, base64, file-encodings

I am sending image as **base64_encoded** in **JSON_PAYLOAD** from front-end **AJAX** request, on the other side I am using **LUMEN API** to accept that request, get file and store it in db in field having **LONGBLOG** type, but problem is that when I dump my API method to see the payload sent by front-end it dumps nothing.

my payload is:

```
{
  data:example_base_64_encoded_file
}
```

here is api method.

```
public function upload(Request $request){
    dd(request->data);
}
```

It gives error that calling the undefined object and when dump only `dd($request)` it dumps null

**CORS** are already enabled. I also tried to enable content-type as base_64.

Comment: post your full ajax request and show us the output of dd($request)

Comment: What happens if you do `dd($request->get('data'));`?

Comment: Yes I did, then it dumps as null